Derivation of the associated Legendre Polynomials
I have been struggling to find a proper derivation of the associated Legendre Polynomials and a derivation of
$$P_l^{-m}(\mu)=(-1)^m\frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!}P_l^m(\mu)$$
Can someone point to a proper derivation of the associated Legendre Polynomials and the form for negative $m$?

The associated Legendre differential equation is clearly invariant under the transformation $m\to -m$, which means that we already know that
$$P^{-m}_l=C(m,l)~P^m_l$$
In order to choose the correct constant factor $C(m,l)$, we want to maintain the the orthogonality relation:
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{P^m_l(x)P^n_l(x)}{1-x^2}\mathrm dx=\frac{\Gamma(l+m+1)}{m~\Gamma(l-m+1)}\delta_{mn}$$
, which we can generalize to allow for negative $m$ (since we dont want to allow $\langle P^{-m}_l,P^{-m}_l\rangle $ to be negative):
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{P^m_l(x)P^n_l(x)}{1-x^2}\mathrm dx=\frac{\Gamma(l+m+1)}{|m|~\Gamma(l-m+1)}\delta_{mn}$$
Plugging in $(-m,-m)$ gives
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{P^{-m}_l(x)P^{-m}_l(x)}{1-x^2}\mathrm dx=\frac{\Gamma(l-m+1)}{m~\Gamma(l+m+1)}\tag{1}$$
On the other hand,
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{P^{-m}_l(x)P^{-m}_l(x)}{1-x^2}\mathrm dx={C(m,l)}^2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{P^{m}_l(x)P^{m}_l(x)}{1-x^2}\mathrm dx $$ $$ =C(m,l)^2 \frac{\Gamma(l+m+1)}{m~\Gamma(l-m+1)}\tag{2}$$
Equating $(1)$, $(2)$ gives
$$\frac{\Gamma(l-m+1)}{m~\Gamma(l+m+1)}=C(m,l)^2 \frac{\Gamma(l+m+1)}{m~\Gamma(l-m+1)}$$
Thus,
$$|C(m,l)|=\frac{\Gamma(l-m+1)}{\Gamma(l+m+1)}$$
So now we have determined $C(m,l)$ up to a sign. In keeping with the Condon-Shortley phase convention, we arrive at
$$\boxed{C(m,l)=(-1)^m\frac{\Gamma(l-m+1)}{\Gamma(l+m+1)}}$$

What I mean by "in keeping with the Condon-Shortley phase convention" is that this alternating sign is necessary to preserve the recurrence formulae under the subsitution $m\to -m$. It is rather tedious to check this but I encourage you to give it a try.
